# I can't open the correct class that I want

Tags: android, listview, search, textwatcher

Everybody. So, I have a problem with my TextWatcher. My listview works fine. When I click on a specific item from this ListView (lv_arr), it opens a specific class that I want to, so far so good. But, my textwatcher (I'm using a edit text [layout] that searches the items from the listview) when I search a item (name) from one of string (listview) instead of openning a specific class that corresponds the name of the item, it opens a class according to position. Ex: I search for "Fluke", instead of openning Fluke.Class, it opens BirdHand.class. That's not what I want. I want it to open Fluke.class

This is my code that I'm using. I'm a newbie:

```
public class Searchsort extends Activity {

    private ListView lv1;
    private EditText ed;
    private String lv_arr[]={
        "a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush",
        "a bolt from/out of the blue",
        "a penny for your thoughts",
        "fluke",
        "have a face like thunder",
        };
   private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
   int textlength=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {

               if ("a bolt from/out of the blue".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, BoltBlue.class);
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }

               if ("a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, BirdHand.class);
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }

               if ("a penny for your thoughts".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, PennyThoughts.class);
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }
               if ("fluke".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, Fluke.class);
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }

               if ("have a face like thunder".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, FaceThunder.class);
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }


        }

                });



    // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,   lv_arr));

    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textlength=ed.getText().length();
            arr_sort.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++) {
                if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length()) {
                    if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,  textlength))) {
                        arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>  (Searchsort.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr_sort));

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying arr_sort but comparing with lv_arr.

When the user searches, for example, "fluke" and clicks on the first position, the position is 0, so, the app compares the position #0 of lv_arr and opens the BoltBlue.class activity.

You should compare with arr_sort, because the array must change too.

Hope you understand my explanation.

Comment: Luanjot, could you correct my code... I tried this, as you explained to me, but I can't get it. I don't know Java well, please? :/ Thank you!!!